# Java/PHP - Chat session got refresh on window refresh or opening new window in application

Tags: java, php, session

In web application, i have a chat gadget embedded in web page (.HTML). The back end code of my application Java and the chat gadget communicates with .PHP. I do not have access to .PHP environment.

I can only code in java to handle HTML requests using Java.

**Issue:**
When i click refresh on browser, the new chat session begins every time. 
Even when i jump from one page to other the chat session refreshes and new chat begins.

I am not suppose to do any changes in .PHP environment but need to change code in Java

**Question:** 
I want to mold program in such a way that .PHP environment 
thinks that page has not been refreshed and does not break the session.

I think proxy might be solution but how to implement those? Any other solution for same.

Comment: i think you're right.  A proxy might work for you.  give it a shot and post your code here if you have problems.

Comment: Do you have any link containing implementation of Proxy in Java. I am not getting straightforward links or might be keywords are not correctly used. Thanks

Comment: I'll add an answer with some proxy info

Answer (score 1):

To build a proxy, first create a ServerSocket on a port that the widget will talk to, then start accept accepting connection on it.

As new connections come in, create a new Socket to the php server.  Then you have to pipe the input from one to the output of the other and vice-versa.

That's a generic proxy.  For your case you'd have to add some logic to detect that a connection already exists (probably with a cookie), then reuse the existing socket instead of creating a new.

Unfortunately, it will be a bit of work to parse the input, and get the protocol to match what php is doing.

(edit to add example)

Here's a barebones generic proxy example to get you started.  Run this then point your browser to localhost.

```
public class Proxy {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(80);
    Socket browser = server.accept();
    Socket remote = new Socket("google.com", 80);
    pipe(browser.getInputStream(), remote.getOutputStream());
    pipe(remote.getInputStream(), browser.getOutputStream());
    remote.close();
    server.close();
}

private static void pipe(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    while(in.available() == 0) {
        Thread.yield();
    }
    while(in.available() > 0) {
        int data = in.read();
        System.out.write(data);
        out.write(data);
    }
}
}
```

A working solution would need to be multithreaded (or async) and instead of just piping the data between servers you'll have to get in there and inspect it, then decide if you need to open a new socket or re-use an existing one.

Comment: Thank you for that, i will follow that and will share progress with you. One more thing, Will that able me to preserve history of Chat gadget on new page too? Like user had already chat, and i want that already chat content on new page after refresh is done or Do you think i also need PHP code to look upon?

Comment: It really depends on how the gadget is written. If it allows you to send previous message to it (maybe it will think they are new), then you could keep a history on the proxy. -- By the way, this is all a lot of work.  Since you already have a java server to work with, you might want to consider some off-the-shelf chat clients before hacking this one.  I guess it depends on your circumstances and level of ambition.